# Instagram follower cound and bio

Tags: html, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, instagram, instagram-api

I've a personal instagram bot.I have to filter profiles based on follower count and bio. At the beginnning I get with scrapping (It goes profile and extract the info)  but after a while it gave http 429 too many requests error. Because it has to go instagram profile. And whatever I did, I could not find a solution. Last time I create Instagram API but it only extracts business profile data. Do you have a solutions about that? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Instagram's API has rate limits. You can only make 100 or so requests per hour (the number may vary depending on API or account).

[More information](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/overview/rate-limiting/)

Comment: As I mentioned I don't use API right now. Because I cannot get non-business profile's follower count and bio with API. Therefore I'm scraping. But after a while, I got HTTP 429 too many requests error when I try to goes any profile page.

Comment: oh, you'll encounter similar limits with their web apps. Most sites implement some kind of request limiting to prevent scraping, though they're less explicit about those limits.